# JSON not parsing from API call

Tags: java, android, json

After looking on here a lot I haven't found something similar to this problem.

I'm getting the JSON from my API call however it isn't parsing I went through the steps I'm using and getting a Parsing error that is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 1` I will post examples of everything below and hopefully someone can tell me what I did wrong (I've been using the same thing to parse other objects and they worked not sure why this doesn't)

***Expected JSON***

```
{
"user":{
    "id":1054776,
    "email":"fghrklhjkltghskj@gmail.com",
    "username":"user1496654688",
    "first_name":null,
    "last_name":null,
    "last_login":null,
    "email_confirmed":false
    }
}
```

***RegisterRequest.java***

```
public class RegisterRequest {

    private Context mContext;
    private Map<String, String> mCredentials;

    public interface RegisterFeedback{
        void onRegisterSuccess(RegisterResponse response);
        void onRegisterFailed(Exception exception);
    }

    public RegisterRequest(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void sendRegistration(String email, String password, RegisterFeedback feedback) {
        String url = Constants.BASE_URL + Constants.REGISTRATION_URL;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        mCredentials = new HashMap<>();
        mCredentials.put("email", email);
        mCredentials.put("password", password);

        final RegisterFeedback registerFeedback = feedback;

        GsonRequest<RegisterResponse> request = new GsonRequest<>(url, RegisterResponse.class, null,
                Request.Method.POST, mCredentials, new Response.Listener<RegisterResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(RegisterResponse response) {
                registerFeedback.onRegisterSuccess(response);
                PreferenceConnector.writeString(mContext, "authToken", response.getAccessToken());

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                registerFeedback.onRegisterFailed(error);

            }
        });

        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                10000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
        ));

        RequestFactory.getInstance(mContext).addtoRequestQueue(request);

    }

}
```

***RegisterResponse.java***

```
@Parcel
public class RegisterResponse {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @SerializedName("last_login")
    private String lastLogin;
    @SerializedName("email_confirmed")
    private String emailConfirmed;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastLogin() {
        return lastLogin;
    }

    public void setLastLogin(String lastLogin) {
        this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
    }

    public String isEmailConfirmed() {
        return emailConfirmed;
    }

    public void setEmailConfirmed(String emailConfirmed) {
        this.emailConfirmed = emailConfirmed;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

***GsonRequest.java***

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends JsonRequest<T> {

    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private Map<String, String> bodyJson;
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private Map<String, String> headers;
    private Response.Listener<T> listener;
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";

    private static final String PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE =
            String.format("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers, int method, @Nullable Map<String, String> bodyJson,
                       Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

        super(method, url, getFormDataString(bodyJson), listener, errorListener);
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.bodyJson = bodyJson;

        if (headers == null) {
            this.headers = new HashMap<>();
        } else {
            this.headers = headers;
        }

        this.headers.put("client-id", Constants.API_CLIENT_ID);
        this.headers.put("client_secret", Constants.API_CLIENT_SECRET);
        this.headers.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
    }

    private static String getFormDataString(Map<String, String> formData){

        StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder();
        if (formData != null) {
            for (String key : formData.keySet()) {
                params.append("&").append(key).append("=").append(formData.get(key));
            }

            return params.toString().substring(1);
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return bodyJson != null ? bodyJson : super.getParams();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response){
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json;
            String encoding = response.headers.get("Content-Encoding");

            if (encoding != null && encoding.equals("gzip")) {
                json = unpackData(response.data);
            } else {
                json = new String (
                        response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            }

            return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, clazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    private String unpackData(byte[] data) {
        String output = "";

        try {
            GZIPInputStream gStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gStream);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String read;
            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                output += read;
            }
            reader.close();
            in.close();
            gStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }

        return output;
    }


}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance :D

Comment: Log your response. It looks like it's not JSON, and its very first character is `s`.

Comment: Try using JSON.parse. And also share the javascript  code snippet where the json is parsed.

Comment: @Daenarys where would I add this?

Comment: @Bilal looks like your using volley, enable logging with VolleyLog.DEBUG = true; Then in function parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) Log response.data and share the output pls.

Comment: @RishabhBhatia where do I find the results of the output? I can't see anything in my log cat

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv what part of my response do you want? I can't find this `s` character

Comment: @BilalMH Which Gson version are you using?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I am using version 2.7

Comment: @BilalMH You wouldn't see a log until you add VolleyLog.v("TAG", response.data); at top in your parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) function.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected JSON has comma at the end after "email_confirmed":false, 
Please rectify it and try again.

Comment: There's 3 more fields after that and there's no comma on the last field.

Comment: 'user' is JSON object. I do not see any provision made to extract data from JSON object for parsing it to RegisterResponse data.

Try something like this in your web api response method
 
JSONObject userObject = obj.getJSONObject("user");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            RegisterResponse registerResponse = gson.fromJson(userObject.toString(), RegisterResponse.class);




Implement custom json object request class for the same. Hope it helps/

Comment: I don't have a web api response method? Sorry this is confusing me

Comment: you are getting response in    @Override
            public void onResponse(RegisterResponse response) {
                registerFeedback.onRegisterSuccess(response);
                PreferenceConnector.writeString(mContext, "authToken", response.getAccessToken());

            } but you have not made any provision to get "user" object data.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now. I've done what you said and it works! Thank you :)))